# Why does the JHipster define a type named EntityArrayResponseType?

Tags: angular, jhipster

Why does the JHipster generated Angular code define a type named EntityArrayResponseType in each data service class and use it as the return type from data access methods?

e.g.

student.service.ts:

```
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IStudent[]>;

query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<IStudent[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
}
```

Why not just defined the query() method with a return type of HttpResponse? The code would be easier to read this way.

Comment: I don't see a specific reason in the commit message, but it helps to reduce duplicated variables in the generated service (only have to change one line to change it everywhere) and also simplifies the template file

Comment: I would guess that you may be right about your second point, i.e. it simplifies the Yeoman code generation template perhaps. I don't see the value in the first reason though because this part is not likely to change and having this type reduces clarity in the code since EntityArrayResponseType doesn't tell you much about what is returned by the query() method.

Comment: I see your point.  If you use an IDE though, the type completion shows `HttpResponse<IStudent[]>` as the response type for `query()`

Comment: Good point. You are saying that, where the service is used, such as in a call on the query() method from an angular component, the IDE shows `HttpResponse<IStudent[]>`. However, when you look at the service implementation code, it is harder to read because of this type definition that has no apparent value to me as a developer. This is not a standard Angular approach. I've not seen this suggested in any Angular tutorials or books.

Comment: Feel free to open a pull request